# Mosync Build Error: Whats it mean

Tags: c++, build

**I am delving into Mosync & its going pretty good, but for some reason I am getting the following errors which I dont understand:**

> First error = "Error: Unresolved symbol '__ZN4MAUI6LayoutC1EiiiiPNS_6WidgetEii',"
>   Second Error = "Error: Unresolved symbol '__ZN4MAUI7ListBoxC1EiiiiPNS_6WidgetENS0 _18ListBoxOrientationENS0_20ListBoxAnimationTypeEb',"

*I have commented below which line the error refers to.* I have also cleaned my project & rebuilt, this worked the 1st time but now it wont work & its creating these types of errors for other creations of widgets such as labels. What does this error mean?

```
#include <MAUtil/Moblet.h>
#include <MAUI/Layout.h>
#include <MAUI/ListBox.h>
#include <MAUI/Label.h>
#include <MAUI/EditBox.h>


using namespace MAUtil;
using namespace MAUI;

/// Functions ///
float toFahrenheit( float fahrenVal );
float toCelsius(float celsiusVal );


class TemperatureMoblet : public Moblet
{
public:
    TemperatureMoblet()
    {
        mainLayout  = NULL;
        mainListBox = NULL;
        initScreen();
    }

    void keyPressEvent(int keyCode, int nativeCode)
    {
        // todo: handle key presses
    }

    void keyReleaseEvent(int keyCode, int nativeCode)
    {
        // todo: handle key releases
    }

    void initScreen()
    {
        mainLayout  = new Layout( 0, 0, 100, 600, NULL, 1, 3 ); // ERROR HERE  
     mainListBox = new ListBox( 0, 0, 100, 200, mainLayout,
                                   ListBox::LBO_VERTICAL, ListBox::LBA_LINEAR,
                                   true ); // 2nd error here
                  ......
                           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a linking error which means that your code compiled fine, but when trying to bring the compiled code together some parts are missing. In this case it seems to be the UI classes. Generally this is because maui.lib is missing under the additional libraries. It is however strange that it worked the first time, perhaps you accidentally changed to the debug configuration?

If go right click on project -> properties -> MoSync project -> Build Settings. Is maui.lib among the additional libraries? Check both for the release and debug configurations (it should be mauiD.lib in the debug configuration).

If it doesn't work perhaps you can paste the whole build log somewhere, including all the calls to pipe-tool.